# Splitting String Characters into a Torch Tensor

Tags: string, split, lua, torch

I have 2 Strings in Lua:

```
a = '01234'
b = '12345'
```

I want to split them into characters and load them into a Torch Tensor, like this:

```
tens = torch.Tensor{{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function split(str)
    tbl = {}
    for c in str:gmatch('.') do
         table.insert(tbl, c)
    end
    return tbl
end

a = '01234'
b = '12345'

tens = torch.Tensor{split(a), split(b)}
```